how to make your dapp (frontend application) trustable for solana transactions
I deployed my website and now phantom or solflare or what ever is telling me always the same. My site is not secure or what ever.

const { connection } = useConnection();
  const { publicKey, sendTransaction, signTransaction } = useWallet();

  const createTransaction = async (
    amount: number
  ): Promise<TransactionResponse | null> => {
    if (!publicKey) {
      throw new Error("Wallet not connected");
    }

    const latestBlockhash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

    const transaction = new Transaction()
      .add(
        SystemProgram.transfer({
          fromPubkey: publicKey,
          toPubkey: new PublicKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WALLET_ADDRESS || ""),
          lamports: solToLamports(amount),
        })
      )
      .add(PRIORITY_FEE_IX);

    transaction.feePayer = publicKey;
    transaction.recentBlockhash = latestBlockhash.blockhash;
    transaction.lastValidBlockHeight = latestBlockhash.lastValidBlockHeight;

    return { transaction, latestBlockhash };
  };

  async function signAndSendTransaction(
    transaction: Transaction,
    blockdetails: BlockDetails,
    checkTransactionCallback: () => Promise<void>
  ) {
    if (signTransaction) {
      const res = await signTransaction(transaction);

      await checkTransactionCallback();

      toast.dismiss();
      const signature = await sendTransaction(res, connection);

      toast.loading(
        "Verifying Transaction... Please DO NOT close the window..."
      );

      return { signature, blockdetails };
    }

    return null;
  }


For phantom wallet try using this:
Change your dApp to use the signAndSendTransaction method. Information about this method can be found here: https://docs.phantom.app/phantom-deeplinks/provider-methods/signandsendtransaction

You need to reach out to Blowfish which is what Phanton and Backpack use to flag suspicious sites.
This is their email to use review@blowfish.xyz
